# is there a way to pass data directly in Step definition without passing in feature file?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-junit, feature-file

i want to use dataprovider to pass data directly into step definition without passing from feature file, as i want to pass null values as well. here is what i am doing.

Scenario: User should get empty field highlight, when that fields is empty and clicked submit.  When Submit is clicked after providing values in nethier or either of Reg Id or PC

```
@Test(dataProvider = "getData")
    @When("^Submit is clicked after providing values in nethier or either of Reg Id or PC$")
    public void submit_is_clicked_after_providing_values_in_nethier_or_either_of_reg_id_something_or_pc_something(
            String regvalue, String pcvalue) throws Throwable {
//code
}

@DataProvider

    public Object[][] getData() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[3][2]; // 3 is number of combinations and 2 is number of values
        // 1st set
        data[0][0] = "Username1";
        data[0][1] = null;
        // 2nd set
        data[1][0] = null;
        data[1][1] = "Password1";
        // 3nd set
        data[2][0] = null;
        data[2][1] = null;
        return data;
}
```

Error i am getting is

> Step [^Submit is clicked after providing values in nethier or either of Reg Id or PC$] is defined with 2 parameters at 'com.commcard.stepdefinition.StepDef.submit_is_clicked_after_providing_values_in_nethier_or_either_of_reg_id_something_or_pc_something(String,String) in file:/D:/Eclipse-Workspace/CucumberProject.CitiCommCard/target/test-classes/'.
> However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments.

Comment: Remove the parameters on your step definition method. The number of arguments on your feature file should always be equal to your step definition method

Comment: Okay, but any idea how else i can declare a variable in step definition and fetch the data from data provider

Comment: If you want you can directly call the method getData() . But what bothers me is the way you write your steps. If I were you, separate the step definition for entering inputs and clicking submit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a yml file as a data-lookup. For JSON style testing I would advocate this. As you can use a regular fixture or build it up mid-process.

So you could have something like this.

```
Given I have a valid request to create a user
But the username is invalid
```

```
Given I have a valid request to create a user
But the username is too short
```

```
# yaml file

user:
  create:
    issues:
      username:
        invalid: "Can't Use W3!rd char$"
        too_short: "usrnm"
```

Then your steps just use whatever programming language you use and convert the yml into a data lookup (Hash/List), and alter the keys.